# Defining relationship between two entities having many to many relation

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework

I have two entities namely `users` table and `project` table, below is what attributes or columns the have

**Users Table**

Col1 : uid `(primary key)`

**Project Table**

Col_1: projectId `(primary key)`

Col_2: uid `(references users table)`

The relation is that a user can have many projects and a project belongs to a single user.

Now I want to add the feature of sharing projects between users such as a user can share multiple projects with multiple users.

What is the best way to do this in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships should be modeled by adding a third table.

**ProjectUsers**

```
Col1: uid
Col2: projectId
primary key over the pair of columns: (uid, projectId)
```

This way you can add multiple rows for a given user, meaning the user works on multiple projects.

Likewise multiple rows for a given project, meaning the project is shared among multiple users.